Google Cloud Profiler Shows Only Grey Bars in Flame Graphs Without Stack Data (Python)
I'm encountering an issue with Google Cloud Profiler across all of my tracked Python applications where the flame graphs frequently show grey bars, often labeled "Unknown - No Python thread state." In some cases, the profiler does display function names, but the detailed stack data is generally missing.
Setup Details: 
Python Version: 3.11.2
Google Cloud Profiler Version: 4.1.0 
Environment: Debian 12 hosted in GCP
https://i.sstatic.net/oTgUFsXA.png
The flame graph shows more function names but still has many grey bars, indicating incomplete stack data.

Has anyone encountered a similar issue with Google Cloud Profiler showing only grey bars or incomplete stack data?
Are there any specific settings or configurations I might be missing that could cause this?

Steps I've Taken:

Verified Python Profiler Initialization
Tested with Pure Python Code
Called the profiler at the very beginning of the code execution, right after the application starts.
No significant warnings or errors were found, even with verbosity set to verbose=3.
Expected Behavior:
The profiler should display detailed stack traces for Python code, providing full visibility into the application’s performance.


Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
